# How to determine the distance from an obstacle without knowing its location

Tags: java, collision-detection, collision

I am writing a code where I have a world filled with various obstacles (of rectangular shapes). My robot which is a circle, originates randomly at any place inside the world. I assume that it has a range sensor on its head and want to get the distance between the nearest obstacle/boundary wall which is in its straight line of view.

I am using a random orientation between 0 and 360 degrees to orient the robot and use sin and cos of orientation to move the robot in the same orientation. But how can I get the distance between any obstacle or the boundary wall along this orientation? It should be able to tell me the distance of the first object it encounters in its vision which would be an angle from 0 to 360.

Please provide me a hint of logic how to encounter this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you ask how to identify the objects within the orientation/angle of vision? Or you want to know how to calculate the distance between 2 points?

Comment: @JSlain I just want to know the distance from the first obstacle or if no obstacle is there in line of vision then the boundary wall

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the angle, the robot's position and the position of all the obstacles, you could have a function like this:

- if the angle if less than 90 or greater than 270 you increment the x coordinate by 1, otherwise you decrement by 1
- you make a for loop from the current x coordinate until the edge of the world (I don't know how you have the world implemented), scanning for any obstacles at position (x, x*tan(angle)), incrementing or decrementing in accordance with the step above
- the first obstacle you run across, return sqrt(x^2 + (x*tan(angle))^2) - that's just the pythagorean theorem

Answer (score 0):

Here's what **i think** you could do.
In real game development, they uses a lot of optimization tricks, often giving approximates for better performances.
Also note that there's a lot of libraries out there for game development, that probably could get you what you want a lot simplified.

But anyway, here's what i'ld do.

1. identify object you'd pass through if you go straight forward.
2. identify the nearest one, in the list of objects you just made.

1:

A)

- make a formula for your position/angle in the form y = mx + b
- [y = tan(angle)x + (positionY - (tan(angle)*x))]

B)

- for each object, divide the object in multiple lines segments (2 points).
- check if the segment crosses the line made by the formula in point A
        (if a point is smaller and the other is greater than the same X value in the formula, it's crossing)
- do the same thing for your world boundaries

2: [This part is more tricky (to do in programmation).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Intersection_of_two_lines_in_the_plane)

Next, you have to find the position where your robot orientation formula intersect
with all the lines you previously identified.

For each line, you must again turn the line into a y=mx+b
Let say we have:

```
y=3x+5 and 
y=5x+1

3x+5  = 5x+1
3x-5x = 1-5
-2x   = -4
x     = 2
```

Then you replace x with 2 in either formula, you'll get the intersection point:

```
y = 3(2)+5 = 11
y = 5(2)+1 = 11
```

So these two lines intersect on point **(2, 11)**

Next you have to see if that point is in the [**domain**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of you're robot path formula.

Since your robot is looking at a single direction, and the formula we made in point 1.A is infinite in both directions, you must ensure the line intersection you found is not in the back of your robot (unless he moves backward...)

I guess you can make it simple, look at cos(angle) signs, then look at the position of the intersection point, if it's to the left of your robot, and cos(angle) is negative it's fine.

Finally,

Once you found ALL the intersect point, you can find the nearest one by using the Pythagorean theorem **sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)**

Also, note that it won't work for 90 and 270 angles, since tan(90) doesn't exists.

In that case, just look if both points of the segments are at both side of your robot, and the intersect point is in the right direction, it means you pass through it.

Again, there's a lot of place for optimization.